# how to setup robot framework on Visual Code Studio

Tags: robotframework

How to setup Visual Studio so that i can run robot framework file? I am able to save files on VS code as .robot. it tries to open up chrome browser as soong as i run below robot code.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation      Robot Framework test script
Library            SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***
${host}            11.11.11.11
${username}        username
${password}        password
${alias}           remote_host_1

*** Test Cases ***
Test SSH Connection
    Open Connection     ${host}        alias=${alias}
    Login               ${username}    ${password}    delay=1
    Execute Command     hostname
    Close All Connections
```

I tried to run this code using eclipse but it gave error msg "No keyword with name 'Open Connection' found." even though sshlibrary is already installed. this code runs fine on "RIDE" IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a `tasks.json` (under `.vscode`) with the following content:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run robo tests",
            "command": "robot",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/<your-folder-containing-yur-tests>"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "test",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```